# How to use ngIf inside a button?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a button

```
<button class="mx-2" mat-button type="button" (click)="close()"
        name="buttonClose">
    <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
    {{t('commonActions.cancel')}}
   </button>
```

where i have to show the whole button when on PC but only show the button without `commonActions.cancel` when on mobile.

I use isMobile() function for that but i dont know where to place the ngIf, so that only the text gets added/removed, not the button or icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your best option is to use `<ng-container>` in this case:

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="!isMobile()">{{t('commonActions.cancel')}}</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the text in a text tag like (span, p ... ) and add the ngIf inside it , here's an example :

```
  <button class="mx-2" mat-button type="button" (click)="close()"
            name="buttonClose">
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="!isMobile()" >{{t('commonActions.cancel')}}</span>
       </button>
```